# 12.04 Unity middle mouse activation of compiz window scaling

Tags: unity, compiz, scale-mode

That's about the summary of my problem. Just updated to 12.04 and Button2 will no longer activate the compiz 'Scale' facility for window switching. There doesn't seem to be any binding conflicts (in compiz config .. assuming this is the right place to set it?).

Does someone have some advice?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I read your question correctly, I was able to set middle mouse button to enable Window scale. From what I see, it is no longer part of the default settings but you can easily set it this way using [CCSM [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager).

Once you have installed it, open CCSM and search for Scale.

[image: Open scale]

Then go to *Bindings* tab in Scale and click on *Initiate Window Picker* (the third option with a mouse icon next to it).

[image: Mouse option]

Click on the checkbox next to *Enable* and choose *Button2* in the dropdown list.

[image: Enable middle button]

Now that all the settings are set, log out and back in and you would now be able to enable Window scaling using your middle mouse button.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed suggestion. That was the first thing I tried, it didn't work. So I tried it again .. and it didn't work [repeat ad-nausium].

Comment: @Empty Weird. I have tried twice now and it works. Could you try running `unity --replace` in a terminal and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: unity --replace: no process found, gui crashed.

Comment: @Empty I think one other setting is probably conflcting. Check Viewport switcher - http://imgur.com/uALdW

Comment: viewport switcher is disabled

Comment: Getting weirder and weirder. I am now quite sure I probably misread your question. What do you expect to happen when you middle click?

Comment: OK unity --replace (run with root) reset my unity configuration back to zero. Bye Bye 3 hours effort

Comment: I want the middle mouse button to activate the 'Scale' effect of Compiz, it really is that simple.

Comment: Why did you run that with root? o.O Does Super-W do what you want to do with Scale-effect?

Comment: Same problem here. Keyboard bindings work for the scale. http://i.imgur.com/fwQcb.png However, the mouse bindings dont. Earlier, if I would push my pointer in the top-right corner, the windows would scale. Now it doesnt. I suspect a recent upgrade has caused it. unity --replace gives this as OP: http://pastebin.com/5fy6MSU8

Comment: Wow, I restarted the machine. Its working now. Never knew Ubuntu to  be a restart-to-apply kind of OS.

Comment: @theTuxRacer I am glad the solution eventually worked for you. Does it also mean that my solution is correct after all?

Comment: @Empty I just tested my solution on a clean 12.04.1 install and it works. I am now of the opinion that you are using Unity-2D. What do you get for `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: @theTuxRacer Also, if you would want to bind hot corners to scale windows, you can try [this solution.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74504/how-do-i-set-clicking-on-a-screen-edge-to-switch-viewports/99216#99216)

Comment: @theTuxRacer Ubuntu is not a restart-to-apply OS, but some features require you to log out and log back in, or sometimes to restart the interface. In the case of Unity, you just have to run `unity` to restart it.

Comment: @jokerdino I would think so, yes. My laptop wasn't turned off since maybe 15 days. I just update the packages, reset the bindings, did `unity --replace` and rebooted the laptop. It works now!

Comment: @theTuxRacer: O_o...